# How to use enum?

Tags: java, android, enums

I am writing a code for an app. But I am getting the following error.

I am posting the screen shot. Please help me to resolve the error.

[image]

The error is in the part where I use enum.

```
public static enum Mode
  {
    static
    {
      CORRECT = new Mode("CORRECT", 2);
      Mode[] arrayOfMode = new Mode[3];
      arrayOfMode[0] = NO_ASYNC_TASK;
      arrayOfMode[1] = NO_DOWNLOADED_DRAWABLE;
      arrayOfMode[2] = CORRECT;
    }
  }
```

Thanks every one for the answers.

Comment: Post the code as part of the question, not a screen capture that's hard to read and can't be quoted in an answer.

Comment: You should refer to the syntax of the java language. Google enum example java and you will find your syntax errors.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html, http://whathaveyoutried.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your definition needs some enhancements. First of all there is no need to define the enumeration as static. Also, you need to put all of your enumerations in a specific independent class not with other classes, this would make your solution more organised. Additionally, 'static' is a reserved keyword for the language, so no need to use static for an inner block.

You can define the enumerations with or without integer values as in the followings:

```
public enum Mode
{
    NO_ASYNC_TASK,
    NO_DOWNLOADED_DRAWABLE,
    CORRECT
}
```

or

```
public enum Mode
{
    NO_ASYNC_TASK(1),
    NO_DOWNLOADED_DRAWABLE(2),
    CORRECT(3);

    private final int id;
    Mode(int id) { this.id = id; }
    public int getValue() { return id; }
}
```

Comment: I don't have a compiler in front of me but I don't think the second example would compile.

Comment: public static enum Mode{
    
      CORRECT = new Mode("CORRECT", 2);
      Mode[] arrayOfMode = new Mode[3];
      arrayOfMode[0] = NO_ASYNC_TASK;
      arrayOfMode[1] = NO_DOWNLOADED_DRAWABLE;
      arrayOfMode[2] = CORRECT;
    
  }
  I know it is not recognising the body.

Comment: Thanks for notifying me @assylias, you are right there were some minor mistakes in the second example and I corrected them in the edited version :)

Answer (score 10):

Declare enum as

```
public static enum MODE
{
    NO_ASYNC_TASK,
    NO_DOWNLOADED_DRAWABLE,
    CORRECT
};
```

and Use the enum in the following manner

```
MODE.NO_ASYNC_TASK
```

Comment: @silwar: Dont add extra stuff at your own.

Comment: @Sahil: Hi, I am not adding any extra stuff. I just suggested to go through link which has extra information about using enum in Android environment

Comment: @silwar: Editing means to correct mistakes in the post, check spellings, correct formating etc. Its not about adding extra stuff to the post. Why dont you post it as a separate answer. It would be more helpfull to the OP as well as for you. You could get good upvotes as well if that link proves to be beneficial.

Comment: @Sahil: Thanks for info. next time I will make sure that I will post extra stuff in separate answer

Answer (score 2):

remove `static` modifier from enum definition or take your enum inside other class

Answer (score 1):

Remove "public" from enum declaration in same class because with in one java file there must be only one public class and also the "static".

Answer (score 1):

Enums are usually used when using constants, act as providing a type for constant.

Instead of saying :

```
public static final int MALE = 1;
public static final int FEMALE = 2;
```

You can say

```
  public enum Gender {
     MALE, FEMALE;
   }
```

and refer to them as `Gender.MALE` and `Gender.FEMALE`.

Without enums, the method to `setGender` needs to accept an `int` (in the above example) and I can pass anything other than 1 or 2. The code in there then needs to check if the int being passed maps to the constant, etc. `Enums` provide a clean and easy way in such situations.