# Java - Remove "Variable", keep assignments with side effects

Tags: java, android, variables, enums

I am starting to develop for Android (And I am starting to think, does it worth it!). Eclipse keeps giving me a lot of strange warnings and errors too! Here is one that kept me frustrated for the last two hours with no luck on Google:

```
private String alertTitle= null;
```

There is an ! mark beside it saying Remove "alertTitle", keep assignments with side effects. What is this?! I am defining a variable exactly as Java states. I am using the variable later:

```
public ASAlertDialog setTitle(String title) {
        this.alertTitle = title;
        return this;
    }
```

Another one that's a little bit similar is defining enum"

```
public enum MyStyles {
     aStyle;
}

public MyStyles myStyle = aStyle;
```

This made Eclipse angry!

Comment: Did you try `public MyStyles myStyle = MyStyles.aStyle;`?

Comment: Enum conventions suggest all Caps for naming style, i.e. A_STYLE

Comment: @ChrisKnight but it is only convention, not a rule

Comment: @marcin your answer is correct. Do you know what to do with the variable warning. I am using this variable already later in the code by setting its value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable is not used, so eclipse informs you about that and therefore you get message `Remove "alertTitle", keep assignments with side effects`

Answer (score 3):

You may be using the variable name by assigning a value to it, but you are **not using the value** stored in the variable. To do that, you must use the variable name to retrieve the stored value, and do something with this retrieved value somewhere in your code.

Eclipse tags the variable as unused when the value is **never retrieved** (*or more generally, it's never possible to retrieve it**). It means you're merely assigning values to it, but never making use of them anywhere. This makes the variable an unnecessary memory hog, hence the warning.

* `public` and `protected` variables won't get the warning because they can be retrieved in other classes even if they aren't retrieved within the class they are declared in, and even if they are currently never retrieved in any class (*it may happen in the future due to library use*).

For the `enum`, it should be:

```
public MyStyles myStyle = MyStyles.aStyle;
```

This is because an `enum` is something like a class, with the constants acting similar to static variables in the class. (*This is just an analogy, not exact an language definition.*) You would retrieve enum constants the same way you retrieve variables from an external class that are defined as `static`.

Answer (score 1):

For enums, you need to declare it as

```
public enum MODE
{
   NO_ASYNC_TASK,
   NO_DOWNLOADED_DRAWABLE,
   CORRECT
};
```

Check my [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14050949/1777090) answer for more information

And the warning is because you might not be using `alertTitle` variable after declaring it.

Comment: You don't need to declare enums static.

Comment: No, I am using it later in public methods.

Answer (score 1):

To your first question:

It just means that your variable isn't being used, so you can safely remove it. The warning will disappear once you start using the variable in your code. Side-effects are explained here:

http://www.cs.umd.edu/~clin/MoreJava/Intro/assign.html

Check under "Is Assignment an Expression?"

To your second question:

There is no ';' in defining an enum. Check this:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Comment: No, it wasn't the semi-colon. Marcin's comment on my question is the correct answer. Regarding the variable, I am using it.

Comment: There is nothing to post :) just a simple public method to set this variable.

Comment: I see your edit now. Your variable isn't being read. It's just being assigned to. As it is, it's private (can't be read from outside) and isn't being read inside the class - hence the warning. If you use the variable's value inside the class, the warning should disappear.

Comment: you're right. Is there any way to remove such stupid warning?

Comment: There is, actually. A very useful feature of Eclipse is that you can right-click the warning and it should give you options on how to fix it. One of those options will be to suppress the warning. You can do this yourself by just adding @SuppressWarnings("unused") on the line above the variable declaration.

Comment: And, by the way, you can move your marker to anything that's underlined yellow (warning) or red (error) and hit Ctrl+1 to pull up the quick-fix menu. Extremely useful for solving all sorts of problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
public enum MyStyles {
     aStyle;
}

public MyStyles myStyle = aStyle;
```

Regarding to your String, maybe Eclipse informs you that your variable is never used.

By the way,

```
private String alertTitle;
```

is null by default, so why do you set "= null"?

Comment: I think you just copied my enum :) Setting it to null to make the code readable (it's something I used to do)